Infinite coin Toss and filtration - what events are in the uncountable power set that are not in the terminal sigma-algebra?
Let $\Omega:=\{0,1\}^{\mathbb N}$. We define coordinate projections $X_i:\Omega\rightarrow\{0,1\}$ and set $\mathcal F_n:=\sigma(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$. How would i approach showing that $\mathcal F_\infty:=\sigma\Big(\bigcup_{i=1}^n\mathcal F_n\Big)$ is strictly smaller than $\mathcal P(\Omega)$? In other words, what kind of event is in $\mathcal P(\Omega)\setminus \mathcal F_\infty$?
